# Call remote script with parameter

Tags: powershell

I have a script on a remote server like so:

```
function ExtractMetadata()
{

param([string]$url)

add-pssnapin 'microsoft.sharepoint.powershell'

set-alias STSADM "${env:commonprogramfiles}\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\BIN\STSADM.EXE"

STSADM -o mv-populatemetadata -url $url convention1 -usemvprefix
```

}

I want to call this from another server using invoke-command, and pass in a url parameter. What would be the right syntax to do this?

Thanks

Comment: So if the function is in a file on server A and you are running on server B, which server do you want the code to actually run on?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a `scriptblock`. The following turns your function into a `scriptblock`, and then uses the `-ArgumentList` of `Invoke-Command` to pass the URL as an arugment.

```
$ExtractMetadata = {
    param([string]$url)
    add-pssnapin 'microsoft.sharepoint.powershell'
    set-alias STSADM "${env:commonprogramfiles}\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\BIN\STSADM.EXE"
    STSADM -o mv-populatemetadata -url $url convention1 -usemvprefix
}
Invoke-Command -Computer Server456 -scriptBlock $ExtractMetaData -ArgumentList "http://www.serverfault.com"
```

**Edit1**

Has Powershell remoting been configured on the remote server? `Test-WSMan` should return with 4 lines of info if it has been (wsmid, ProtocolVersion, ProductVendor, ProductVersion)

```
Test-WSMan -Computer Server456
```

If PSR is enabled, what happens if you run a simpler remote command like this?

```
Invoke-Command -Computer Server456 -scriptBlock { get-wmiobject win32_computersystem }
```

Comment: I can't reply due to not enough points. Clayton - the command works but I get this error: ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @GS Please edit your question to show exactly what you ran and the complete error that you got.